# EmberJS - Calling a controller method within a routes setupController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a **controller** with a few methods attached to it. I have a relevant **route**. I added the methods inside the **controller** so that they can be re-used in a few other places. These methods retrieve some data from the server. Inside the **setupController** of the route, I'm calling these methods and everything works as expected.

But once I **concatenate** the files, Ember throws an error saying the method I'm trying to call is undefined. I use **grunt-contrib-concat** plugin but also tried changing it to use **uglify**. Still the same issue. I don't think there is anything wrong with the concatenation as it always worked previously. However, I never used the setupController before other than to set properties. Added the sample code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
/*  Ember 1.10.0 Debug version */

/* Route */
App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() { return []; },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);

        /* Setting values on the controller works */
        controller.set('currentDate', new Date());

        /* Calling a method works normally but throws error when minified */
        /* Error: dashboard undefined is not a function */
        controller.addNumbers();
    }        
});

/* Controller */
App.DashboardController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    currentDate: null,
    addNumbers: function() {
        return 1 + 2;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say you need to look at the minified code or the order that the code is being concatendated, but it's not a problem with `setupController`.

I created a JSbin with your example and run it through Uglify, and it works correctly.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mizudelupi/2/

If you can create a JSbin with your minified, concatendated code, we can take a look and help.